# Proof of the starting part of theorem 1.17 Rudin ( Complex and Reals)

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

The proof I would like is of the following fact:

Put $\delta_n = 2^{-n}$. To each positive integer n and each real number t corresponds a unique integer $ k = k_n(t)$ that satisfies $k \delta_n \le t < (k+1) \delta_n$ .

This is the start of the theorem 1.17  Rudin.

Answer (score 3):

This comes from the Archimedean property: let $k+1$ be the least integer larger than $t/\delta_n$.

Comment: But what about uniqueness?

Comment: @Monolite think of it this way: Since $k\delta_n \le t < (k + 1)\delta_n$, $k$ lies in the interval $(\frac{t}{\delta_n} - 1, \frac{t}{\delta_n}]$. Since that interval has length one, it cannot contain more than one integer. So $k$ is unique.

Comment: Another way to think about uniqueness is that $k+1$ is the least integer, and therefore unique (if both $a$ and $b$ are least, then $a \le b$ and $b \le a$)